# Is there any extension like emmet for react native in VS CODE?

Tags: react-native, vscode-extensions

Emment for react is working fine after I added the JSReact  to settings JSON in VS code.

Emmet for react

'''.main>h2.heading>p.body '''     this translated into

```
<div className="main">
  <h2 className="heading">
    <p className="body"></p>
 </h2>
</div>
```

**But the same cannot work for react native.**

Questions
1)Is there a way to activate emment for react native?
2)What are the options to type react native codes faster with shortcuts?

> Already tried below solution and it works for react only

adding below code to settings.json in VS code

```
 {
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
     "javascript": "javascriptreact"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SaugatMaharjan.nativeemmet

**But notice** it seems that this extension works only in .js files, not with .tsx for example